How to fit exponential data in Gnuplot?
I'm working on a project where I need to fit some experimental data to an exponential function using Gnuplot. However, I'm new to Gnuplot and not sure how to do this efficiently.
I've been searching through Gnuplot documentation, but I haven't found a clear solution to my problem yet. Could someone provide an example or a step-by-step guide on how to perform an exponential fit to my data using Gnuplot?
I appreciate any help or suggestions you can offer. Thanks in advance!
DATA:
1    -1.9946
1.2  -2.15925
1.4  -2.39905
1.6  -2.50725
1.8  -2.50005
2    -2.54025
2.2  -2.56675
2.4  -2.6166
2.6  -2.64155
2.8  -2.6209
3    -2.63775
4    -2.65615
5    -2.66575
6    -2.664
7    -2.6669
8    -2.6791
9    -2.66865
10   -2.6687



COMMENT :
First. One have to chose a convenient equation model. I suppose that you chose
y=a+b.exp(c.x) with a and c negative.
Second. One have to perform a non-linear regression to compute approximates of the parameters a, b, c.
The usual methods of non-linear regression involve iterative calculus starting from "guessed" initial values of the parameters. Sometimes the calculus fails due to initial values too far from the unknown correct values.
Very good initial values can be computed thanks to the method shown below. This method of regression isn't iterative and doesn't requires initial "guessed" values.


If the accuracy of the fitting isn't sufficient use the above values of a, b, c as "guessed" values in your non-linear regression software.
For reference of the non-iterative method : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales

It should be possible fairly easily if you define a suitable function for it to use as a model that describes your data. I suggest something along the lines of:
 f(x) = a + b*exp(c*(1-x))

where a ~= -2.7, b ~= 0.7, c ~= 2 and then the incantations to fit and plot it
 fit f(x) "data.dat" using 1:2 via a, b, c
 plot "data.dat" using 1:2 with points, f(x)

More info on fitting exponentials is online at "Fitting exponentials in GnuPlot for Beginners". In the past I have generally found the Gnuplot group on Usenet still has some very knowledgeable Gnuplot gurus lurking there. You need a Usenet client and an aggressive kill file to zap the spam though.
I have found Gnuplot very powerful but also a steep initial learning curve and sometimes a bit quirky on some of the more esoteric plotting styles. I suggest saving the scripts that you get working at least until you have a better working knowledge. It is somewhat cryptic and very unforgiving of syntax errors.
